# Looking for a story/book on Intelligent whales and floating cities

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for a book (maybe a story) that I read in the early 1980's as part of a science fiction literature class in college.  Can't remember author or title.  Most I can remember is that it had intelligent whales and floating cities.  One of the species of whales was attacking floating cities.  Any ideas?  Thanks,

Comment: It's a long shot, but perhaps *Triplanetary*?  There's a scene where one of the Nevian's floating cities is attacked by intelligent fish.  Doesn't quite sound right though: they're fish, not whales, and that was only one relatively short scene in a much longer novel.

Comment: You might also like to check out [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/5930) in case it jogs your memory.  You can edit your question to add any additional details you might think of.  Welcome to Stack Exchange!

Comment: [Google Books link](https://books.google.co.nz/books?id=K1vYCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PT144&dq=nevian%20cities&pg=PT139#v=onepage&q=nevian%20cities&f=false) for the possibly relevant scene in *Triplanetary*.

Answer (score 7):

Was it perhaps [*Cachalot*, by Alan Dean Foster (ISFDB link)](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3424)? [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cachalot_(novel)) says:

> Cachalot is an ocean planet where humans have begun building floating cities. It is also the same planet where all of Earth’s cetaceans were transplanted six hundred years ago after the Covenant of Peace was enacted with all intelligence-enhanced ocean dwellers. Five of these cities have been destroyed when a middle-aged scientist and her late-teen daughter are dispatched to the planet to discover the source of the attacks.
>
> The novel title comes from the French word cachalot, meaning "sperm whale". This word was applied to the sperm whale when the mammals were actively hunted in Earth’s oceans.
>
> The novel features a new musical instrument called "neurophon" producing not only tunes but also nerve sensations on human skin and irritating alien creatures found on the planet.